# Check element has been clicked before running function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple elements that users select (by clicking on them) in an attention task. Currently, I have code in which the elements turn red when clicked. When they are done, users will click "next" to see another task. Critically, before they move on, they *must* make a selection.

So I need to check that the user has selected one of the elements.

If someone has not selected one of the elements before clicking "next", then I'll write an error message. But first I'm having trouble checking that an element has been clicked in the first place. Preferably, I'll also be checking *which* element was clicked.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px white;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: #ffcc66;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

    .buttons:hover {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red !important;
      border: solid 3px black !important;
    }

    #next {
      background-color: gray;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px white;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="next">
    <p>next</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.buttons').click(function() {
      $('.buttons').removeClass("selected");
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
      // check that one of the elements has been clicked
      // if an element has not been clicked, then show error message
      // console.log(which element was clicked)
      $('#buttonGallery').hide();
      $('#next').hide();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at least one of the elements has been clicked, then that `buttons` class element will have class `selected`. So, we can use that logic like:

1. No element was selected, if `buttons` do not have any `selected` class like:

   ```
   $('.buttons.selected').length === 0
   ```
2. One element was selected, if `buttons` have a `selected` class like:

   ```
   $('.buttons.selected').length > 0
   // Or, simply the else part in the demo.
   ```
3. To get the `id` of the `buttons` clicked we can simply use:

   ```
   var id = $('.buttons.selected').attr('id');
   ```

```js
$('.buttons').click(function() {
  $('.buttons').removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});

$('#next').click(function() {
  // check that one of the elements has been clicked
  // if an element has not been clicked, then show error message
  if ($('.buttons.selected').length === 0) {
    console.log('Please select one element first.')
  } else {
    // which element was clicked
    var id = $('.buttons.selected').attr('id');
    console.log(id + ' was clicked');

    $('#buttonGallery').hide();
    $('#next').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons{width:150px;height:50px;border:solid 2px #fff;text-align:center;color:#000;cursor:pointer}
#buttonGallery{margin:10px;padding:10px;border:solid 2px #000;width:155px}
#button_1{background-color:#fc6}
#button_2{background-color:#9ff}
.buttons:hover{background-color:red!important;border:solid 3px #000!important}
.selected{background-color:red!important;border:solid 3px #000!important}
#next{background-color:gray;margin:10px;width:150px;height:50px;border:solid 2px #fff;text-align:center;color:#000;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonGallery">
  <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
    <p>button_1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
    <p>button_2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="next">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the button has `selected` class after clicking on next button and then show error messages if there is no selected class.

```js
$('#error').hide();

$('.buttons').click(function() {
  $('#error').hide();
  $('.buttons').removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});

$('#next').click(function() {
  // check that one of the elements has been clicked
  // if an element has not been clicked, then show error message
  // console.log(which element was clicked)
  const isSelected = $('.buttons').hasClass('selected')

  if (!isSelected) {
    $('#error').show()
    return false;
  }

  const selectedButton = $('.buttons.selected');

  $('#buttonGallery').hide();
  $('#next').hide();
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonGallery {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 155px;
}

#button_1 {
  background-color: #ffcc66;
}

#button_2 {
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.buttons:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
  border: solid 3px black !important;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red !important;
  border: solid 3px black !important;
}

#next {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="buttonGallery">
  <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
    <p>button_1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
    <p>button_2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="next">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
<div class="error" id="error">Nothing selected</div>
```